# Vbscript issue : executed vbscript with help of wrapper class

Tags: c#, vbscript, wrapper, pdfbox

I have created a wrapper class to access PDF FORMS using PDFBox  , by using the wrapper I m trying to execute it with VBScript..

Here is my wrapper class (Class Library) with COM enabled

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel;
using org.apache.pdfbox.util;
using org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form;

namespace PDF.API
{
    public class PDFDocument
    {
        private PDDocument PD;

        public void load(string PDFPath)
        {
            PD = PDDocument.load(PDFPath);
        }

        public PDDocumentCatalog getDocumentCatalog()
        {
            return PD.getDocumentCatalog();
        }

        public void save(string PDF_Path)
        {
            PD.save(PDF_Path);
        }

        public void close()
        {
            PD.close();
        }
    }
```

here is my vbscript

```
Set TestPDF = CreateObject("PDF.API.PDFDocument")
Set test  = PDFDocument.load("D:\\PDF_FORMS\\sample_form.pdf")
Set PDDocumentCatalog = test.getDocumentCatalog()
Set PDAcroForm = PDDocumentCatalog.getAcroForm()

Set PDFField = PDAcroForm.getField("Forenames")
PDField.setValue("VBSCRIPT")
test.save("D:\\PDF_FORMS\\a.pdf")
test.close()
```

Now it throws me Object required for `PDDocument`

could not able to resolve this issue 
can any one help me out please

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ansgar Wiechers and Aphoria already mention, your `Load` is a method of your `PDFDocument` class, and to simplify yourself, you may use the same name as variable name in your .vbs, i.e.:

```
Set PDFDocument = CreateObject("PDF.API.PDFDocument")
```

Next issue I see, is that your `Load` method is a `void` (not return value), so the syntax should been like this:

```
PDFDocument.load "D:\path\to\file_a.pdf"
Set PDDocumentCatalog = PDFDocument.getDocumentCatalog()
' ... '
PDFDocument.save "D:\path\to\file_b.pdf"
PDFDocument.close
```

And I not touched C# recently, but as far as I remember you need a Constructor.

```
namespace PDF.API
{
    public class PDFDocument
    {
        private PDDocument PD;

        public PDFDocument()
        { //class constructor
        }

        public void load(string PDFPath)
        {
            PD = PDDocument.load(PDFPath);
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change `PDFDocument.load...` to `TestPDF.load...`.

```
Set TestPDF = CreateObject("PDF.API.PDFDocument")
Set test  = TestPDF.load("D:\\PDF_FORMS\\sample_form.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set TestPDF = CreateObject("PDF.API.PDFDocument")
Set test  = PDDocument.load("D:\\PDF_FORMS\\sample_form.pdf")
```

You're using `PDDocument` without instantiating it first. You probably meant to do this:

```
Set test  = TestPDF.load("D:\\PDF_FORMS\\sample_form.pdf")
```

As a side note: I'd recommend to escape backslashes inside your class. In VBScript it's usually not required to escape backslashes in paths (WMI notwithstanding), so it may confuse your users if you handle this differently.

Comment: Set TestPDF = CreateObject("PDF.API.PDFDocument")
Set test  = PDFDocument.load("D:\\PDF_FORMS\\sample_form.pdf")

even if i try with PDFDocument wrapperclass name where it contains the load method, throws me the same object required for PDFDocument

Comment: Even if you rename the **object variable** `PDDocument` to `PDFDocument` you still don't initialize that variable anywhere. See updated answer.